# How can I push this subview into it's own subclass?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a basic subview that slides up 80 from the top of the screen when a button is pushed. I've created another class - AdvancedView - that inherits from UIView. What I would like to do Is first of all, push all the code that's responsible for creating this subview into it's own class: AdvancedView. I would then like to somehow set it to where the top 100 of the subview is show showing when the main view loads. I'm going to put a button at on the top showing portion of this subview that will toggle it up and down (I know how to code the button). Here is the code that I need to put into AdvancedView and have the top 100 showing when the main view CalcViewController loads:

```
#import "CalcViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"
#import "AdvancedView.h"

@property (nonatomic, strong) AdvancedView *myNewView;
@synthesize myNewView = _myNewView;

- (AdvancedView *) myNewView
{
    if (!_myNewView) _myNewView = [[AdvancedView alloc] init];
    return _myNewView;
}

- (IBAction)subView {

    self.myNewView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
    self.myNewView.frame = CGRectMake(0,489, 320, 200);
    [self.view addSubview:self.myNewView];
    float bottomYOfDigitBeingDisplayed = 75;

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [self.myNewView addSubview:button];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0];
    self.myNewView.frame = CGRectMake(0, bottomYOfDigitBeingDisplayed, 320, 400);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UIView subclass could look like this

.h

```
@interface AdvancedView : UIView {

}

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation AdvancedView

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect{

   if(self = [super initWithFrame:rect]){

       self.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

       UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
       [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(display:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
       [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

       [self addSubview:button];

   }

   return self;



}

- (void) display:(id)sender{

    float bottomYOfDigitBeingDisplayed = 75;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0];
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, bottomYOfDigitBeingDisplayed, 320, 400);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

@end
```

Your UIViewController could look like this

```
#import "CalcViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"
#import "AdvancedView.h"

@property (nonatomic, strong) AdvancedView *myNewView;
@synthesize myNewView = _myNewView;

- (AdvancedView *) myNewView
{
    if (!_myNewView) _myNewView = [[AdvancedView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                                  CGRectMake(0,489, 320, 200);];
    return _myNewView;
}

- (IBAction)subView {

    int advancedTag = 199998;
    self.myNewView.tag = advancedTag;

    if(![self.view viewWithTag:advancedTag]){
        [self.view addSubview:self.myNewView];
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems great but I can't seem to get a portion, say the top 100, of the subview to show on the bottom of the screen when the the main view loads. I want users to know that the sub view is there and to be able to click a button on the top of the subview to make it expand up towards the top of the screen. Is there any way to do this. Maybe by somehow setting in it's setter or getter so that it loads as soon as CalcViewController loads?

Comment: self.myNewView.frame.origin.y = 480 - 100; You can set this whenever you want and it should show the top 100 portion of the view on your sub view.

Comment: I just tried setting that in a couple of different locations and I'm getting an error message saying Expression is not assignable. I tried setting it in both the subView action(connected to a button), and when that didn't work I tried setting it in a myNewView setter.

Comment: CGRect newFrame = self.myNewView.frame; newFrame.origin.y = 480 - 100; self.myNewView.frame = newFrame;  This is because the frame is a readable property on your newView.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry to keep throwing questions at you but where exactly would I set this at.

Comment: Whenever you need to make the top 100 portion of you advanced view appear. You can do this on the viewDidAppear in your CalcController.